# Struts 2 : "The requested ressource is not available"

Tags: java, struts2, web

I implemented a simple example with struts 2.

But I have this error when clicking on the action :

"The requested ressource is not available"

It seems that apache server can't find the jsp file.

Here is the error in frensh.

```
  Etat HTTP 404 - /StrutsTraining/classes/Hello.jsp

type Rapport d''état

message /StrutsTraining/classes/Hello.jsp

description La ressource demandée (/StrutsTraining/classes/Hello.jsp) n'est pas disponible.
```

My struts.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="action1" class="org.training.Hello">
            <result name="Hello">classes/Hello.jsp</result>
            <result name="goodBy">classes/GoodBy.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

My Web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>StrutsTraining</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Jsp files are under :

```
/StrutsTraining/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes
```

Comment: any special reason you places them inside classes folder?

Comment: There is a struts2 plugin to enable JSPs within the classpath I think, check the struts2 plugin registry if this is something you must do, but simply don't put them there would provide a quicker resolution.  I would recommend /WEB-INF/content as a good starting point, then if you decide to use the totally awesome struts2-conventions-plugin and save yourself a lot of time you'll be slightly more comfortable (by default that is where it likes the JPSs to live).

Comment: it was a mistake. no reason to put jsp in  the classpath. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to put jsp's in classes folder create a jsp folder inside WEB-INF folder and keep your jsp files.

```
        <action name="action1" class="org.training.Hello">
            <result name="Hello">/WEB-INF/jsp/Hello.jsp</result>
            <result name="goodBy">/WEB-INF/jsp/GoodBy.jsp</result>
        </action>
```